# Accessing elements in Set

Tags: python, set

I am quite new to Python and thus struggling with its structures. Please ignore my silliness. I tried my best to find a solution but failed so far.

I  have a set "self.gamma" which looks like

```
{<pomdpy.solvers.alpha_vector.AlphaVector object at 0x0000015E7B5F8908>, <pomdpy.solvers.alpha_vector.AlphaVector object at 0x0000015E7B5F8E48>, <pomdpy.solvers.alpha_vector.AlphaVector object at 0x0000015E7B5F8948>
```

I want to access its elements and I can do it this way:

```
[av.v for av in self.gamma]
[av.action for av in self.gamma]
```

which gives

```
[array([-95. ,   9.5]), array([  9.5, -95. ]), array([-0.95, -0.95])]
[1, 2, 0]
```

respectively. There are two types of data in the set - "v" (short for value) and "actions". Here is what I want to do:

1. Do what I did without the for loop
2. Access individual arrays from within self.gamma, e.g., self.gamma.v[0] should give me  array([-95. ,   9.5])

I hope I was clear with my question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you need to store them in a list rather than a set. Can you change the type of self.gamma i.e., `self.gamma = list(self.gamma)`?

Comment: What do you mean by *Do what I did without the for loop*? Just trying to get an idea of your expected output. Should the output of `self.gamma.v` be the equivalent of `[av.v for av in self.gamma]`?

Comment: @Craig self.gamma = list(self.gamma) returns the same set as before except that the curly brackets are now square brackets

Comment: @C.Nivs Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Ok, this question might seem basic, but why are you using a `set` for `self.gamma`, rather than a `list`? And if you want `v` and `action` apart, could you not store them separately like `self.v = [av.v for av in gamma]` and `self.action = [av.action for av in gamma]`?

Comment: @C.Nivs I am actually using an existing function (https://github.com/pemami4911/POMDPy)  which by default uses set, but I need to make modifications thus need to manipulate the set.

I want to avoid for loops because the size of the arrays in many scenarios ar huge

Comment: @lost_and_found fundamentally, you can't do what you did without a for-loop. You can convert to a list, e.g. `list(self.gamma)`, which *does not return "a set with square brackets", it returns a `list`. You can now access individual elements by index. A `set` supports various set operations, e.g. intersection, union, difference, and most importantly, very efficient membership testing. You need to take a step back and choose your data structures to fit your use case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you. I will try to fit my case that way, but being sort of a novice in Python, I am really unfamiliar with lots of structures of python and thus quite hard to understand the function package I am trying to manipulate. What I asked for would make my life easy if there was (is) a solution

Comment: @lost_and_found i don't know how to be more clear, `set` objects do not support indexing like you want, let alone mapping attribute access over it's elements, (no built-in python data struture supports that).